# How to calculate the square of Frobenius norm of a matrix faster?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Let's say A is a column vecter with shape (m,1), B is a row vector with shape (1,p), C is the matrix product of A and B, i.e. C=AB, so C's shape is (m,p).

Now I want to compute the square of Frobenius norm of C, i.e. sum_i sum_j c_{ij}^2 (sum of all the squares of C's elements)

Note that c_{ij}=a_i*b_j, a_i and b_j are the elements in A and B. So I can rewrite the formula above.

sum_i sum_j c_{ij}^2=sum_i sum_j (a_ib_j)^2=sum_i a_i^2 *sum_j b_j^2

The complexity of formula sum_i sum_j c_{ij}^2 is O(mp).

And the complexity of formula sum_i a_i^2*sum_j b_j^2 is O(m+p), since A and B has lower dimention than C.

However, this trick is off when A and B are both matricies.

Consider this, A is a matrix with shape (m,n), B is a matrix with shape (n,p), C is the matrix product of A and B, i.e. C=AB, so C's shape is also (m,p).

I still want to compute this sum_i sum_j c_{ij}^2

Note that c_{ij}=sum_k a_{ik}*b_{kj}, so

sum_i sum_j c_{ij}^2=sum_i sum_j(sum_k a_{ik}*b_{kj})^2

Therefore, at this time, there is no trick I can use like before (the vector version)

So my question is, I need matrix C and I also need the square of Frobenius norm of C, would it be faster using C directly than using A and B?

square of Frobenius norm of C = trace of CC^T

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. It's an interesting question, but StackOverflow doesn't render latex, so all these dollar signs are making your question harder to read, not easier. But perhaps https://cs.stackexchange.com or https://math.stackexchange.com would have been more suited for that question (and they do render latex).

Comment: this is probably a math.stackexchange question.

Comment: @Stef Thank you! I will edit my question here and re-post it on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

You want the square of the Frobenius norm of AB. The Frobenius norm is
preserved by rotations, which leads to the following O((m+n+p)
n<sup>2</sup>)-time algorithm.

Assuming that m ≥ p and n ≥ p (this shouldn’t be critical if we define
the degenerate cases the right way), let A = QR be the reduced
QR-decomposition of A and <sup>t</sup>B = Q′R′ be the reduced
QR-decomposition of <sup>t</sup>B. We want the Frobenius norm of AB =
QR<sup>t</sup>(Q′R′) = QR<sup>t</sup>R′<sup>t</sup>Q′. Since Q and Q′
are semi-orthogonal, it suffices to find the Frobenius norm of
R<sup>t</sup>R′. Since R and R′ are n × n matrices, we can use the
straightforward O(n<sup>3</sup>)-time algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I also need the matrix C. So if I calculate Frobenius norm from C instead of using matrices A and B, would it be faster?  The square root of the trace of CC^T equals to the Frobenius norm of C.

Comment: @KevinHsu if you need C anyway, you should just compute it and then take its norm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, Could you please explain the notation where t is in superscript and then you write B?

Comment: @Martund transpose of B